# New Mac mini Logitech K350 keyboard

Tags: mac

I'm trying to set up a new Mac mini with A Logitech K350 keyboard.  Since the mini has no cd drive its not possible to load the keyboard software. Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use an external CD drive - I have several that work via USB just as well as an internal CD drive.

Another way is to download the drivers. I'm assuming you've tried this and - given the keyboard is Logitech - the drivers may only be available to Windows platforms. There are several ways to run Windows applications on a Mac, although I'm not sure how well these solutions work for drivers.

Comment: The only cd drive I have around is in a G4 PowerBook,  could I access the mini with that?  With no mouse or keyboard I haven't been able to set up the mini, I'm stuck on the first screen which asks me to turn on a mouse and keyboard.

Comment: Not worth making it more complicated than it needs to be. Sounds like using a USB keyboard for setup would be your best bet. Borrow one from a friend or relative if you can. Even if its PS2 - PS2 to USB converters are cheap and a solid solution. You shouldn't need a mouse for the initial setup, Tab can prove useful switching from option to option.

Answer (score 0):

### On another pc

Boot a linux live media, insert the software CD and copy its contents.
Insert the software media on your machine and install it.

### Download the drivers

Self explanatory.

### Other Solutions

External usb drives work wonders.